# how to generate pdf using json in table format in react

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

how to generate json array of objects to pdf in react

used jsPDF to generate

how to plot in table format
React Js/Java Script

```
export class AppComponent { 

  convert(){
    var item = [{
      "Name" : "XYZ",
      "Age" : "22",
      "Gender" : "Male"
    },
    {
      "Name" : "XYZ",
      "Age" : "22",
      "Gender" : "Male"
    }];
    var doc = new jsPDF();
    var col = ["Name", "Age","Gender"];
    var rows = [];

    doc.autoTable(col, item);

    doc.save('Test.pdf');
  }
}
```

output:

```
Name   Age   Gender
XYZ    22    Male
ABC    20    Female
```

Comment: can you explain more about this requirement?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/201m911xvy configure it